# Using IE filters for background gradients

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I am using this property in my CSS to create a gradient for IE.

```
.icons,
#nav {
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(   startColorstr='#9e9ccf', endColorstr='#423f88', GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

After applying this I can see pretty gradients as expected. However, My icons no longer have border-radius applied and my #nav z-index fails and my submenus fail to load as expected and get clipped based on #nav height and width. In all IEs.

Comment: can you be more explicit give some code?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/eyidim/5/

Comment: http://jsbin.com/eyidim/5/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE's old proprietary `filter` styles are not compatible with `border-radius`. They use an activeX control that has square corners and overrides any rounded corners you may try to use. This is a known bug and has no work-around.

The other problem with `filter` being an activeX control is that it carries with it all the bugs and quirks that activeX controls have. This includes messing up layering, and other fun stuff like that. My advice is to avoid using `filter` at all costs.

I'll note that `border-radius` only works in IE9 upward anyway, so your problem with that doesn't apply for IE8 or earlier.

**Solution:** I recommend you try out [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/). This is a javascript library that plugs into IE6 - IE9, and gives those browsers better support for standard CSS3 gradients. It does it using VML graphics, so it doesn't need to use `filter`, and thus doesn't have the bugs that `filter` gradients can cause. (It does have some quirks of its own, but they're minor in comparison, easily worked around, and well documented on the CSS3Pie site). The other benefit is that it allows you to use standard CSS code for all browsers including older IE versions. Big win.

Oh, and it also does `border-radius` for IE6-8, which is an added bonus for you. (and yes, it works fine with the gradients)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Will IE ever stop being a time consuming piece of crap? Many thanks

Comment: @scottgemmell - yes it will. In fact IE10 is a pretty decent browser. (your question said that the problem is in all IEs, but actually IE10 won't have this problem because it supports CSS3 gradients as standard and removes support for the old `filter` style).